# Different Article alternative layout for each category

Tags: layout

As the title show I want to have different Article Layout for each Category.

For example
Article 1 (category A)-> layout_1
Article 2 (category A)-> layout_1
Article 3 (category A)-> layout_1

Article 1 (category B)-> layout_2
Article 2 (category B)-> layout_2
Article 3 (category B)-> layout_2

I know to set this from each item (from Option tab Alternative Layout) but it´s posible to set this for each category (and not item by item) ?? Inside each Category set up under Alternative Layout I only have the "list" layouts for this category but not the unique item show.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

1. Go to Menus->Your Menus->Add New Menu
2. Create new menu of type Category List/Blog
3. In menu creation page, select "Template Style" option to your alternate style

Comment: Thanks but this was my first try. There I set up the style for Category blog view, but I want is setup the style for the "article" view.

Comment: Articles will inherit style from its category if there is no menu item exist for the article.

Comment: @Nagarjun Well, how do you define the layout other than default.php?